# Run php daemon on web server

Tags: php, loops, web

Im trying to write a chat script for my website. The idea is to run an infinite loop to check if any messages are incoming. I wrote a little test script to test this.

```
<?php

$test = false;

while(!$test) {
    if($test == true) {
        echo "<h1>hello</h1>";
    }
}

?>

<input type="button" onclick="<?php $test = true; ?>" />
```

Obviously the page doesn't load because of the infinite loop. How can I run a sort of daemon process on the side, so the page can load and function normally whilst continually checking for incoming messages?

Also, in the script shown above I understand that I could just use a function to receive the result but I don't really want to have to click a button every few seconds to check for incoming messages.

Thanks!

Comment: you have assigned false to `$test` variable and you are checking `!$test` means always condition true, so the loop will never end

Comment: If you have a webserver running on the server this is your deamon. Every request will be handled on sending data.

Comment: You need either a server-side push technology (just php won't do it) or periodic javascript polling from the client side. What you have now can never work because by the time the output is sent to the browser, your php script will have finished.

Comment: You could use a cronjob to periodically call a .php script